# Wordpress Oxygen Builder stuck on "Tweaking Typography" on loading screen

Tags: wordpress

I've got **Oxygen** 4.5 running on **WordPress** 6.1.1 on a server running **PHP** 8.1 (was 7.4 but I updated it to see if that would fix this issue) and when trying to edit anything with the oxygen builder it gets stuck on that section.

There are no errors coming up in the **Debug Console** in DevTools and the **Error Log** on the server doesn't show any errors linked to this error.

I've done a cache reset through **Oxygen**, **Lightspeed** (our chosen cache plugin) and through the **Chrome** hard reset button but none of them seem to make a difference to the endless loading page of doom we seem to have run into.

Does anyone know where to look to find anything that might be causing this issue? Or anyone had this issue before and have been able to fix it?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

I deactivated my cache plugin and all worked as normal. Set it back on again when editing was complete - just have to remember the same thing again next time!